# Can I apply for Schengen Visa in my home country even though I have stayed in Australia for the last 6 months?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, germany, visa-rejections

This is completely new and weird rule for Schengen Visas. I am currently holding a valid Indian passport but residing in Australia for my studies. I recently came down to India to visit my parents on my vacation and intend to travel to Germany after this. But my documents were returned saying that I do not belong to this "jurisdiction". I was born in Bangalore, India why can't I apply in Bangalore? If someone has done this before or experienced something like this please tell me what options did you use.

Comment: When you say your documents were returned, you mean upon applying in Bangalore you were refused ?

Comment: It looks to me that the embassy made a mistake. Are you sure you applied in the country that you intend to travel first or stay longest?

Comment: There hasn't been new Schengen rules for a long time.

Comment: Today you live in Australia, not in Bangalore. So you should apply from a German consulate in Australia.

Comment: @AyeshK No mistake. It is necessary to apply in the consulate that serves the applicant's place of residence, which is in Australia. Exceptions are to be made only in very limited circumstances. This is not a new rule.

Comment: @phoog or Michael, you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a new rule.  It is expressed in article 6 of the [Schengen visa code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20131018).

If you have a justification for applying outside your country of residence, the consulate can consider the application.  The justification has to be significant, though.  For example if you left Australia not planning to travel to Europe and then changed your plans, you would not be made to go to Australia for a visa.

The [handbook](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf) gives more examples.

You may wish to reapply, including a justification for applying in India.  If you do, you should probably read the handbook to get an idea about the kinds of justifications that will and won't be accepted.

Comment: Please check. The link is not working!!

Comment: @pbu Thanks for letting me know.  Is it okay now?